# NPE when calling setVisibility with ViewFlipper

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragments

I have a ViewFlipper with the following XML Note that this is all contained inside a RelativeLayout

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipperIdentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/identification_face"/>
    <include layout="@layout/identification_rfid"/>
    <include layout="@layout/identification_voice"/>
    <include layout="@layout/identification_pill_dispense"/>

</ViewFlipper>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_button_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <include
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     layout="@layout/test_buttons"
     android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout has the ID of "linear_button_view". Now inside my fragment, I have code to determine the flipping, and that all works. The problem is, that when I get to index 3 of the flipper, I want to hide this layout. All I should have to do is create a field with this ID, and then setVisibility to View.Gone. But I am throwing a NPE when I try to do this.

Inside the class I have a:

```
private View buttonView;
```

Inside my onCreateView, I have the following code

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pilltransferflipper, container, false);
buttonView = v.findViewById(R.id.linear_button_view);
```

This is my method that controls flipper, and is responsible for hiding the view.

```
private void nextState() {

flipperIndex++;
if (flipperIndex >= flipperPillTransfer.getChildCount()) {
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.stateChange(State.SESSIONFINISHED);
} else {
    flipperPillTransfer.showNext();
        Log.d(TAG, "FLIPPER INDEX: " + flipperIndex);
    if(flipperIndex == 3) {

        buttonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }

}
```

When I put a Log.d message inside the flipperIndex condition, It is returned fine, it seems that the issue is the buttonView.setVisibility part of things. Keep in mind, I am using fragments, so some methods that are available in the main activity may not be available to me. Thanks!

## Here is the logCat

```
09-26 10:05:54.381: D/PillTransferFragment(1719): FLIPPER INDEX: 3
09-26 10:05:54.381: D/AndroidRuntime(1719): Shutting down VM
09-26 10:05:54.381: W/dalvikvm(1719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c2b300)
09-26 10:05:54.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 10:05:54.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 10:05:54.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): at com.example.android.fragments.PillTransferFragment.nextState(PillTransferFragment.java:107)
09-26 10:05:54.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): at com.example.android.fragments.PillTransferFragment.onClick(PillTransferFragment.java:64)
09-26 10:05:54.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
```

Comment: Show this line: PillTransferFragment.java:107

Comment: At line 107, it is this code: buttonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: and does buttonView exist at that point? Have you tested that?

Comment: Maybe here v.findViewById(R.id.linear_button_view);
is start of NPE.

Comment: @Neil it should its field declaration is outside of the method in the class. It gets initialized onCreateView

Comment: @Pasha I have other objects that are initialized that way though. I have buttons that are initialized there as well with SetOnClickListener

Comment: Try to change plase flipperPillTransfer.showNext(); and buttonView.setVisibility(View.GONE); Maybe problem in RelativeLayout...